# I'm doing some basis conditional exercises, and I don't know what the % numbers mean in this code

Tags: python

```
currentYear = int(input('Enter the year: '))
month = int(input('Enter the month: '))
if ((currentYear % 4) == 0 and (currentYear % 100) != 0 or (currentYear % 400) ==0):
       print('Leap Year')
```

I have no idea what the % numbers in the brackets with the currentYear means. I gather it has something to do with leap years, but how does it become %4, %100 or %400?

I don't know what this is all about to be honest...

Comment: To help with your research, do a search for the ‘modulo’ operator. For a general mathematics perspective, Wikipedia has a nicely written article.

Comment: Python has *very* good [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Comment: And to be honest, any books, classes or tutorials that have exercises or assignments about leap years should have mentioned the `%` operator already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % symbol in Python is called the Modulo Operator. It returns the remainder of dividing the left hand operand by right hand operand. It's used to get the remainder of a division problem.

So 100 % 5 == 0

or

100 % 3 == 1 ---> Remainder equals 1